# Accord.Net Predicting that the chart will go upwards on not

Tags: c#, machine-learning, svm, logistic-regression, accord.net

So my goal is to predict that the chart will go upwards or downwards.
We know a series of y values . 
ex : -45 , -120 , -105 , -130 , -125 , 115 , -130 , -130 and this chart went upwards (1 is the answer)

All of that with the usage of the Accord.NET machine learning framework.
We have around 5000-6000 sections of training data.

But at this point I only have a 50 % accuracy .

I have tried all of the basic stuff : Naive Bayes , C45 , Logistic Regression , Support Vector machine .

What should I do to make this work ? Do I need more y values ? Or is it even possible ? If not what could make it possible to do ?

Comment: How exactly do you think it's going to guess "upwards" from that data? A linear trendline over it is almost flat. Based on last three samples it's going down. If you reject outliers (as many algorithms do) it's definitely headed down. How do you get "upwards" from it?

Comment: This is from a database .. I do not make up stuff :)

Comment: It would be the goal to make a good classifier for this database .

Comment: This answer is obviously late, but you could have taken a look at the [Resilient Backpropagation sample application](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Sample-applications#resilient-backpropagation-rprop): Download it, run it, click the "Time-Series" button, click the "Load" button and select randomly an example. It should perform something similar to what you needed. In your case, if you have really long time series data, you could consider much longer observation time windows.